# TextArea loses value on Razor Page post

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I am sure that this is a ASP.Net Core newbie question but I have spend a couple of hours on this and I don't want to spend anymore time on this.

I have a textarea in a form that is working well on the first get but as soon as I post the form, the textarea loses its text. 
What am I missing?

**Settings.cshtml:**

```
<form role="form" id="account" method="post">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="form-control-label">Existing keywords</label>
<textarea rows="@Model.PredefinedKeywordsCount" class="form-control form-control-muted" disabled="disabled">@Model.PredefinedKeywordsSeperatedByNewLine</textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Settings.cshtml.cs:**

```
public class SettingsModel : PageModel
  {
public class InputModel
    {

    }
[BindProperty]
    public string PredefinedKeywordsSeperatedByNewLine { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public int PredefinedKeywordsCount { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }
public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
      var predefinedKeywords = <GetListFromDatabaseOperation>;
      PredefinedKeywordsSeperatedByNewLine = predefinedKeywords.GetListSeperatedByNewLineAsync();
      PredefinedKeywordsCount = predefinedKeywords.Count;
    }    
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
//Some code to save new keywords in database
      }
      return Page();
    }
```

**Update: 5/6/2019**
I changed the code to use List in the page's model binding but now I am unable to bind the list property to the control.

**Settings.cshtml:**

```
<form role="form" id="account" method="post">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="form-control-label">Existing keywords</label>
<textarea asp-for="Input.PredefinedKeywords" class="form-control form-control-muted" rows="@Model.Input.PredefinedKeywords.GetListSeperatedByNewLineAsync()"                                                  disabled="disabled">@Model.Input.PredefinedKeywords.Count</textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Settings.cshtml.cs:**

```
 public class SettingsModel : PageModel
  {
public class InputModel
    {
      public string NewKeywords { get; set; }
      public List<PredefinedKeyword> PredefinedKeywords { get; set; }
    }
[BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
      this.Input = new InputModel
      {
        PredefinedKeywords = await ScrubberDbContext.PredefinedKeywords.ToListAsync()
      };
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
    //Some code to save new keywords in database
          }
          return Page();
        }
```

}[image]

Comment: Browsers will not send the `disabled` element's value to server. Instead, you can use `readonly`.

Comment: Thanks @cem for your input. I learnt something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the application to work by making the following changes:

**Settings.cshtml:**

```
<form role="form" id="account" method="post">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label">Existing keywords</label>
    @{var predefinedKeywordsArray=Model.Input.PredefinedKeywords.Split("|");
string predefinedKeywords = predefinedKeywordsArray[0];
int rows = Int32.Parse(predefinedKeywordsArray[1]);}
<textarea asp-for="@predefinedKeywords" class="form-control form-control-muted" rows="@rows" readonly></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**Settings.cshtml.cs:**

```
public class SettingsModel : PageModel
  {
public class InputModel
    {
      public string NewKeywords { get; set; }
      public string PredefinedKeywords { get; set; }
    }
[BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
      var predefinedKeywords = <GetListFromDatabaseOperation>;
      this.Input = new InputModel
      {
        PredefinedKeywords = $"{predefinedKeywords.GetListSeperatedByNewLineAsync()}|{predefinedKeywords.Count}",
      };
    }
```